# Seeking reliable way to show images in SWT

Tags: java, image, swt

I'm having a lot of trouble simply showing small (40x40) pixel images in SWT.

If my entire window consists of just a composite which is set to `FillLayout`, and its only component is a canvas, then the image displays correctly.

However, as soon as I try to show an image in a more complex window, with a `GridLayout` or `RowLayout` and more components, then the image does not display at all.

Specifically I'm trying to have the image be updated when the user clicks a button. If I provide an image when the window is opened, that one seems to show up somewhat okay, but if I try to update it when the button is clicked, then the image disappears.

So in simple terms, I'm looking for a way to show images which will allow updating the image based on user input (button clicks etc), and which will be able to expand the layout to show the image if necessary.

Can anyone help me with this? I've spent an entire day on this with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your issue is exactly, but this code works for me:

```
private static Display  display = Display.getDefault();
private static Composite[]  cells  = new Composite[6];
private static Color[] colors = new Color[6];

private static Random   random  = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

private static PaintListener listener  = new PaintListener()
{
    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = ((Canvas) e.widget).getBounds();
        e.gc.setBackground(colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)]);
        e.gc.fillRectangle(5, 5, rect.width - 10, rect.height - 10);
    }
};

static
{
    int i = 0;
    colors[i++] = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK);
    colors[i++] = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
    colors[i++] = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
    colors[i++] = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN);
    colors[i++] = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW);
    colors[i++] = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(comp, SWT.NONE);
        canvas.addPaintListener(listener);
        Label text = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
        String textString = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < random.nextInt(10); j++)
            textString += "A";

        text.setText(textString);

        cells[i] = comp;
    }

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Random");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                Composite cell = cells[i];
                for(Control child : cell.getChildren())
                    child.dispose();

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cell, SWT.NONE);
                canvas.addPaintListener(listener);

                Label text = new Label(cell, SWT.NONE);
                String textString = "";
                for(int j = 0; j < random.nextInt(10); j++)
                    textString += "A";

                text.setText(textString);
            }

            shell.layout(true,  true);
            shell.pack();
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Creates something like this on startup:

[image]

And changes the images randomly on button press:

[image]

Comment: try adding some variable length items to it.. e.g, add a label next to each image, with variable lengths of each label, and lets see if it still works properly?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you also make it work with canvas?

Comment: @user2790209 BWT: please also consider upvoting my answer.

Comment: Done. Can I show you my code so you can tell me what I'm doing wrong? For me, I'm still not able to show them properly, if I maximize the window the image disappears. :(

Comment: @user2790209 If you can create an (SSCCE)[http://www.sscce.org], I'm more than happy to have a look. Add it to your question or create a new one.

Comment: It involves about 4 classes, neither is too long. If that's short enough, I can upload a zip for you..

Comment: Or I can give you the git repo url for checking it out from bitbucket, whichever you prefer.

Comment: @user2790209 I would prefer if you could reduce it to the length of my code snippet. While doing so you might even be able to find the problem yourself.

Comment: Its really just one window and the other 2-3 are very simple helper classes.. I can't reduce it further, or it would defeat the point..

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could just take a look and tell me what you think

Comment: @user2790209 Well, then upload it somewhere. I'll have a look some time today.

Comment: I've posted the two most relevant classes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888186/what-am-i-doing-wrong-regarding-this-swt-layout