# What am I doing wrong regarding this SWT Layout?

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to show a simple window in SWT. I want to divide the window into two equal parts, in the left area the user will provide his input, and the right area will show the result of the output.

Specifically, the user will type in some characters in the left area (in a textbox), these will be reflected in a label below the textbox. When the user clicks a 'Process' button, a screenshot of just the label control will be taken using `Awt.Robot.createScreenCapture`. I want to display this screenshot in the right area.

Later on, I want to use optical character recognition to read the label and display to the user what he typed in the textbox. But for now, I'm simply having trouble getting this layout to show up correctly. If I press process, then the screenshot image is displayed in the right column, but if I resize or maximize the window, it disappears.

Here's the code of the relevant classes. First, this is the class which sets up the controls on a composite, and returns the composite using `getControl()`. The composite it returns is then inserted as a `TabItem` in a `TabFolder`:

```
public class ReadChars
{
    //This is the root container to which all the other controls are added. This container is inserted
    //in a TabFolder as a TabItem:
    private Composite container;

    //Left side input column:

    private Group input;

   //Right side output column:
    private Group output;

    private String fontName;
    private int fontSize;
    private int fontStyle;
    private Font font;

    private Text sourceChars;
    private Label sourceCharsLbl;
    private Button processBtn;

    //Code for this is provided later:
    private ImgCanvas sourceCharsImg;

    public ReadChars(TabFolder parent)
    {        
        fontName = "Courier New";
        fontSize = 12;
        fontStyle = SWT.NORMAL;
        initCompontents(parent);
    }

    private void initCompontents(TabFolder parent)
    {
        container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        layout.numColumns = 2;
        layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;
        container.setLayout(layout);

        font = new Font(Display.getDefault(), fontName, fontSize, fontStyle);
        container.setFont(font);

        input = new Group(container, SWT.NONE);
        input.setLayoutData(getGridData());
        output = new Group(container, SWT.NONE);
        output.setLayoutData(getGridData());


        initInputGroup();
        initOutputGroup();
    }

    private void initInputGroup()
    {
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        layout.numColumns = 1;                
        layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;

        input.setLayout(layout);

        getHeadingLabel(input).setText("Options");       
        new Label(input, SWT.NONE).setText("Type the characters to parse below (0-9 and .):");
        String defaults = "012345689.";
        sourceChars = getTextbox(input);       
        sourceChars.setText(defaults);

        sourceCharsLbl = new Label(input, SWT.NONE);
        sourceCharsLbl.setLayoutData( getGridData() );
        sourceCharsLbl.setFont(font);        
        sourceCharsLbl.setBackground( new Color(Display.getDefault(), 224, 224,224) );
        sourceCharsLbl.setText(defaults);

        sourceChars.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("here: " + sourceChars.getText());
                sourceCharsLbl.setText( sourceChars.getText() );
                System.out.println("Text now: " + sourceCharsLbl.getText());
            }
        });                        

        processBtn = new Button(input, SWT.NONE);
        processBtn.setText("Process");
        processBtn.addSelectionListener( getProcessHandler() );     

    }

    private void initOutputGroup()
    {
        //output.setVisible(false);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        layout.numColumns = 1;                
        layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;        
        output.setLayout(layout);

        getHeadingLabel(output).setText("Output");
        new Label(output, SWT.NONE).setText("Source Image: ");
        sourceCharsImg = new ImgCanvas(output );
    }

    protected Label getHeadingLabel(Group parent)
    {
        Font font = new Font(Display.getDefault(), fontName, 16, SWT.BOLD);

        Label result = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
        result.setFont(font);
        return result;
    }

    protected Text getTextbox(Group parent)
    {
        Text box = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        GridData data = getGridData();
        data.widthHint = 200;        
        box.setLayoutData(data);
        return box;
    }

    protected GridData getGridData()
    {
        GridData data = new GridData();
        data.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        data.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        return data;
    }

    protected void updateSourceImg()
    {
        Image screenshot = ImgUtility.getScreenShot(sourceCharsLbl);
        GridData gd = new GridData();
        gd.widthHint = screenshot.getBounds().width;
        gd.heightHint = screenshot.getBounds().height;

        sourceCharsImg.setImage(screenshot);
        sourceCharsImg.getCanvas().setLayoutData(gd);
        sourceCharsImg.redraw();
    }

    protected SelectionAdapter getProcessHandler()
    {
        return new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
            {
                updateSourceImg();
            }
        };
    }

    public Composite getControl()
    {
        return container;
    }
}
```

Here's the code to the `ImgCanvas` class referenced above:

```
public class ImgCanvas
{
    private Composite container;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Image img;     
    private Object layoutData;

    public ImgCanvas(Composite parent)
    {
        container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        container.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
    }

    public ImgCanvas(Composite parent, Image img)
    {
        container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);        
        container.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
        setImage(img);
    }

    public void setCanvas(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (this.canvas != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Calling dispose");
            this.canvas.dispose();
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Canvas is null");

        this.canvas = canvas;
        initCanvas();
    }

    public void setCanvas()
    {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(container, SWT.NONE);
        if (layoutData != null)
            canvas.setLayoutData(layoutData);        
        setCanvas(canvas);
    }

    public void setImage(Image img)
    {
        setCanvas();
        this.img = img; //keep this below setCanvas() to avoid being disposed.
        Composite parent = container.getParent();
        parent.setSize(parent.getBounds().width + img.getBounds().width, 
                parent.getBounds().height + img.getBounds().height);
        container.setSize(img.getBounds().width, img.getBounds().height);
        canvas.setSize(img.getBounds().width, img.getBounds().height);        

        System.out.println("Set image: " + img.getBounds() + ", " + img.toString());
        redraw();
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas()
    {
        return canvas;
    }

    public Composite getContainer()
    {
        return container;
    }

    public Image getImage()
    {
        return img;
    }

    public void redraw()
    {
        System.out.println("redrawing");
        canvas.redraw();
    }

    public void setLayoutData( Object data )
    {
        container.setLayoutData(data);
        canvas.setLayoutData(data);
        this.layoutData = data;
    }

    protected void initCanvas()
    {
        System.out.println("Canvas started");
        canvas.addPaintListener( getPaintListener() );    
        canvas.addDisposeListener(getDisposeListener());
    }

    protected PaintListener getPaintListener()
    {
        return new PaintListener()
        {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Painting");
                if (img != null )
                {
                    System.out.println("Img:" + img.getBounds() );
                    e.gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    System.out.println("Canvas: " + canvas.getBounds() );
                    //canvas.setSize(img.getBounds().width, img.getBounds().width);
                    //canvas.pack();
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Img is null: " + img);
            }
        };
    }

    protected DisposeListener getDisposeListener()
    {
        return new DisposeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Disposing");
                if (img != null)
                {                    
                    Composite parent = container.getParent();
                    parent.setSize(parent.getBounds().width - img.getBounds().width, 
                        parent.getBounds().height - img.getBounds().height);
                    img.dispose();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here's the code for ImgUtility:

```
public class ImgUtility
{
    private static Robot bot;
    private static Display display;
    public static BufferedImage convertToAWT(ImageData data)
    {
        ColorModel colorModel = null;
        PaletteData palette = data.palette;
        if (palette.isDirect)
        {
            colorModel = new DirectColorModel(data.depth, palette.redMask, palette.greenMask, palette.blueMask);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(data.width, data.height), false, null);
            for (int y = 0; y < data.height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < data.width; x++)
                {
                    int pixel = data.getPixel(x, y);
                    RGB rgb = palette.getRGB(pixel);
                    bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y,  rgb.red << 16 | rgb.green << 8 | rgb.blue);
                }
            }
            return bufferedImage;
        }
        else
        {
            RGB[] rgbs = palette.getRGBs();
            byte[] red = new byte[rgbs.length];
            byte[] green = new byte[rgbs.length];
            byte[] blue = new byte[rgbs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rgbs.length; i++) {
                RGB rgb = rgbs[i];
                red[i] = (byte)rgb.red;
                green[i] = (byte)rgb.green;
                blue[i] = (byte)rgb.blue;
            }
            if (data.transparentPixel != -1) {
                colorModel = new IndexColorModel(data.depth, rgbs.length, red, green, blue, data.transparentPixel);
            }
            else
            {
                colorModel = new IndexColorModel(data.depth, rgbs.length, red, green, blue);
            }       
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(data.width, data.height), false, null);
            WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
            int[] pixelArray = new int[1];
            for (int y = 0; y < data.height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < data.width; x++)
                {
                    int pixel = data.getPixel(x, y);
                    pixelArray[0] = pixel;
                    raster.setPixel(x, y, pixelArray);
                }
            }
            return bufferedImage;
    }
}

    public static ImageData convertToSWT(BufferedImage bufferedImage)
    {
        if (bufferedImage.getColorModel() instanceof DirectColorModel) {
            DirectColorModel colorModel = (DirectColorModel)bufferedImage.getColorModel();
            PaletteData palette = new PaletteData(colorModel.getRedMask(), colorModel.getGreenMask(), colorModel.getBlueMask());
            ImageData data = new ImageData(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), colorModel.getPixelSize(), palette);
            for (int y = 0; y < data.height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < data.width; x++) {
                    int rgb = bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y);
                    int pixel = palette.getPixel(new RGB((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF, (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF, rgb & 0xFF)); 
                    data.setPixel(x, y, pixel);
                    if (colorModel.hasAlpha()) {
                        data.setAlpha(x, y, (rgb >> 24) & 0xFF);
                    }
                }
            }
            return data;        
        }
        else if (bufferedImage.getColorModel() instanceof IndexColorModel)
        {
            IndexColorModel colorModel = (IndexColorModel)bufferedImage.getColorModel();
            int size = colorModel.getMapSize();
            byte[] reds = new byte[size];
            byte[] greens = new byte[size];
            byte[] blues = new byte[size];
            colorModel.getReds(reds);
            colorModel.getGreens(greens);
            colorModel.getBlues(blues);
            RGB[] rgbs = new RGB[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < rgbs.length; i++)
            {
                rgbs[i] = new RGB(reds[i] & 0xFF, greens[i] & 0xFF, blues[i] & 0xFF);
            }
            PaletteData palette = new PaletteData(rgbs);
            ImageData data = new ImageData(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), colorModel.getPixelSize(), palette);
            data.transparentPixel = colorModel.getTransparentPixel();
            WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
            int[] pixelArray = new int[1];
            for (int y = 0; y < data.height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < data.width; x++)
                {
                    raster.getPixel(x, y, pixelArray);
                    data.setPixel(x, y, pixelArray[0]);
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Image getImage(ImageData data)
    {
        return new Image(display, data);
    }

    public static void setDisplay(Display newDisplay)
    {
        display = newDisplay;
    }

    public static BufferedImage getRawScreenShot(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        java.awt.Rectangle region = new java.awt.Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        BufferedImage bim = getRobot().createScreenCapture(region);
        return bim;
    }


    public static BufferedImage getRawScreenShot(Control ctrl)
    {
        Point loc = ctrl.getLocation();        
        loc = ctrl.toDisplay(1, 1);
        //ctrl.toDisplay(1, y)

        Point size = ctrl.getSize();          
        return getRawScreenShot(loc.x, loc.y, size.x, size.y);
    }

    public static Image getScreenShot(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        BufferedImage bim = getRawScreenShot(x, y, width, height);
        return getImage( convertToSWT(bim) );
    }    

    public static Image getScreenShot(Control ctrl)
    {
        BufferedImage bim = getRawScreenShot(ctrl);
        return getImage( convertToSWT(bim) );
    }

    public static Robot getRobot()
    {
        if (bot == null)
        {
            try
            {
                bot = new java.awt.Robot();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }        
        return bot;
    }
}
```

**Edit: ** Here is the main class:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ImgUtility.setDisplay(Display.getDefault());
        WinMgr main = WinMgr.getMain();
        Shell win = main.getShell();   
        win.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
        initComponents(win);

        WinMgr.init(win);
    }

    private static void initComponents(Shell win)
    {
        win.setText("Optical Recognition Libraries");

        Rectangle area = win.getClientArea();
        TabFolder tabs = new TabFolder(win, SWT.FILL);        
        tabs.setLocation(area.x, area.y);        

        new TabItem(tabs, SWT.NONE).setText("Read Characters");
        tabs.getItem(0).setControl( new ReadChars(tabs).getControl() );

    }
}
```

And here is the `WinMgr` class:

```
public class WinMgr
{
    private Shell shell;
    private static WinMgr mainWinMgr;
    public WinMgr()
    {
        shell = new Shell();
        initShell();
    }       

    public WinMgr(int style)
    {
        shell = new Shell(style);
        initShell();
    }

    public WinMgr(Display parent, int style)
    {
        shell = new Shell(parent, style);
        this.initShell();
    }

    public WinMgr(Display parent)
    {
        shell = new Shell(parent);
        this.initShell();
    }

    public WinMgr(Shell parent, int style)
    {
        shell = new Shell(parent, style);
        this.initShell();
    }

    public Shell getShell()
    {
        return shell;
    }

    public void setShell(Shell newShell)
    {
        shell = newShell;
    }

    public void center()
    {
        Monitor primary = Display.getDefault().getPrimaryMonitor();

    }

    protected void initShell()
    {
        shell.addListener(SWT.Close, this.getOnClose() );
    }

    protected Listener getOnClose()
    {
        return new Listener()
        {
            public void handleEvent(Event event)
            {
                System.out.println("closing");
                shell.dispose();
            }
        };
    }            
    public static void init(Shell mainWin, boolean open)
    {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();

        if (open)
            mainWin.open();

        while (! mainWin.isDisposed())
        {
            try
            {
                if (! display.readAndDispatch())
                    display.sleep();                    
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }             
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void init(Shell mainWin)
    {
        init(mainWin, true);
    }

    public static WinMgr getMain()
    {
        if (mainWinMgr == null)
            mainWinMgr = new WinMgr( Display.getDefault() );

        return mainWinMgr;
    }

    public static Shell getMainShell()
    {
        return mainWinMgr.getShell();
    }
}
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong or how to improve this would be appreciated.

Comment: The code for `ImgUtility` is missing and where is the main method?

Comment: BTW: You need to dispose all instances of `Font` and `Color` that you create yourself. Otherwise you will run out of system handles.

Comment: @Baz I've added the code for `ImgUtility`. The main method is just setting up the shell, adding a tabFolder to it, and then adding a tab Item, whose control is being fetched via `new ReadChars().getControl()`. If its important I can add its code.

Comment: @Baz I'll add those disposes. thanks

Comment: Yeah, please add the main stuff as well.

Comment: Now `TestImg` is missing... Didn't you say it isn't much code? Look, I'm trying to help, but if you can't come up with a very small [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that reproduces your problem, I probably won't be able to help you, since I don't really have the time to read through 646+ lines of code for every question that is posted...

Comment: @Baz Sorry, don't worry about `TestImg`, it was just some testing code that I've removed. If you've already looked through the first two classes, there really isn't much more. But I understand if you can't read it.

Comment: The only issue I'm having is, 1) why does the image disappear when I resize / maximize the window, 2) If there's a better way to write the layout than the way I've done it in `ReadChars`, 3) If there's any improvements that could be made to `ImgCanvas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here you go, just replace your `ImgCanvas` class with this:

```
private Composite   container;
private Canvas      canvas;
private Image       img;

public ImgCanvas(Composite parent)
{
    container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    container.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    canvas = new Canvas(container, SWT.BORDER);
    canvas.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    initCanvas();
}

public ImgCanvas(Composite parent, Image img)
{
    this(parent);
    setImage(img);
}

public void setImage(Image img)
{
    this.img = img; // keep this below setCanvas() to avoid being disposed.
    System.out.println("Set image: " + img.getBounds() + ", " + img.toString());
    redraw();
}

public void redraw()
{
    System.out.println("redrawing");
    canvas.redraw();
}

protected void initCanvas()
{
    System.out.println("Canvas started");
    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener()
    {
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Painting");
            if (img != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Img:" + img.getBounds());
                e.gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                System.out.println("Canvas: " + canvas.getBounds());
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Img is null: " + img);
        }
    });
    canvas.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Disposing");
            if (img != null)
            {
                img.dispose();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Not sure why you created a new `Canvas` each time you change the image... You can just reuse the old one.

---

Note: **Never** use `.setSize(int, int)` unless absolutely necessary, that's what `Layout`s are for. Read this:

- [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html)

Comment: Was it just switching the layout from `FillLayout` to `GridLayout` that fixed it?

Comment: @user2790209 That and removing the `.setSize()` calls.

Comment: Thanks again. One question. How was this different than the `FillLayout` I was using? Isn't `FillLayout` also supposed to fill in all the space just like the `SWT.FILL` that you supplied in the `GridData`?

Comment: @user2790209 Not entirely sure. Try reverting it back to a `FillLayout` to see if it still works.

Comment: No, setting it to FillLayout causes it to disappear completely. I used FillLayout on both the canvas and the container.

Comment: @user2790209 I can't really explain that to you... SWT is strange sometimes. That's why I basically exclusively use `GridLayout`.

Comment: I think I'll follow in your steps.

Comment: Is this method going to scale if I wanted to e.g show a grid of 3 imgCanvases per row?

Comment: @user2790209 Which part?

Comment: All of it? Not sure I understand

Comment: @user2790209 What exactly should not scale?